# Getting current working directory from a Sandboxed command-line app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I'm now trying to sandbox my command-line app which is written in Objective-C.

#### Issue

When the app was not sandboxed, I could get the directory where the user invoked the app using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath]`.
However, after sandboxing, the app always returns for current directory `/Users/{MY_ACCOUNT}/Library/Containers/{BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}/Data` no matter from where the command-line app was invoked.

#### Example Code

Actually, I wanna know the absolute path to the files which the user passed as command arguments.

So when, for example, I invoke my command-line app like this:

```
$ pwd
/Users/MY_ACCOUNT/Desktop
$ ./foo/my_executable subfolder/myfile.txt
```

The following part:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation:argv[1] isDirectory:NO relativeToURL:nil];
printf("path: %s\n", [[url absoluteURL] fileSystemRepresentation]);
```

returns on **non-Sandboxed** app correctly:

```
path: /Users/MY_ACCOUNT/Desktop/subfolder/myfile.txt
```

but on **Sandboxed** app:

```
path: /Users/MY_ACCOUNT/Library/Containers/BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER/Data/subfolder/myfile.txt
```

This is of course incorrect.

#### Question

Is there any alternative way to get the correct full paths of the passed file path arguments in a Sandboxed command-line app?
Or is it just impossible and it's better I just give up to sandbox my app?

---

### Solution

Finally, I found one of the solution by myself.

The `environment` property in `[NSProcessInfo processInfo]` has the correct current user working directory even the app is Sandboxed.

```
NSDictionary *env = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
NSString *currentPath = env[@"PWD"];
```

At least, when I call the command in Terminal.app, it works. I'm not sure whether this `PWD` exists always.

Furthermore, As @daij-djan pointed out below, we don't have even the read permission for the given arguments. However, anyway the matter of this question is once resolved.

(If there is someone who know the way to read the file of which path was passed as an argument, please tell me as an answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK (I tried this a while ago, so things MIGHT have changed -- which I don't think though)

The paths passed via command line args wouldn't be accessible even if you figured out where they really are :/

===> so: thats my answer.. it is pointless Im afraid because it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, this is another problem. It's really odd a command-line program cannot open files which were given as arguments.

Comment: There are now ways to give command line tools access to those paths if it ships with a host app. At the moment this is also the recommended way by Apple. So this question still makes sense.

Comment: this is for a main CLI app. the op wants non-sandboxed url instead of sandbox. I still dont see how that'd work

Answer (score 0):

This gets the sandboxed path for the current app.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *rootPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Remember that "Sandbox" has to be turned on in project settings before the code above returns the sandbox path.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replay. However, I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Since my app is a command-line, it doesn't have the visual Capabilities tab in the project setting. So I set my entitlements directly in the Build Settings tab, namely with `CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS ` and `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY `. Is it not enough?

Comment: don't see how this is related im afraid